# What good are daggers?

Tags: assassins-creed-2

I've gotten to Venice and I have never so much as drawn my dagger (well, not on purpose.  Thanks, obnoxiously twitchy weapon selector!).  I haven't felt like anything was particularly difficult while using only my main weapon and hidden blades for melee work.

Am I missing out on any dagger awesomeness?  Any special tricks that require the dagger to perform?  Or is it just another piece of assassin bling?

Comment: You mean, besides stealthily attaching parchments in chat?

Comment: Daggers are excellent for opening oranges, I find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same disclaimer as last time: It's been a while since I played this game... and don't have access to my copy (it's on loan to a friend half an ocean away), but if I recall...

Daggers seemed, at least from my own personal observation, much easier to counter-kill with them, and not so good to outright battle with. The sword seemed just the opposite. Sword was nice for outright battle, but not so much for countering. I never really used the hidden blade much for anything beyond starting a fight or making quick work of a lone guard.

As for the special tricks, I've no idea.

Comment: Daggers are faster than swords, but weaker. In practice, this make them easier to counter-kill, but not so good for direct strikes. http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Short_Blade

Comment: I think different enemies are weak against different types of weapons. At least, I found that I got more one-hit kills with the hidden blade on particular enemies - archers for instance.

Answer (score 5):

I liked daggers because they are good for close fights with multiple people. Easy to counterkill with daggers.

In the first game I passed the whole game with a dagger after I got it. It was not the only weapon but it was the best to counter kill. Of course if you willing to risk it, it can be fun to fight with hidden blades, it can not be really used as offensive weapon but great as counter attack weapon.

Comment: Yeah. Counter-kill 'em all!

Answer (score 4):

The daggers are very different. They are faster in nearly every way. They are better with loads of enimies around, since if you see one about to attack you can swiftly switch between different guards.

And a small spoiler (do not read on if you havnt done the romulan lairs):

> You get a very powerful dagger, like the sword of Altair, but in a dagger form. It nearly 2-hit kills everything.